# can only delete when page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to do a todo-list with html5 localstorage and some JavaScript/jQuery. I use an ul and store it, which works fine and I'm able to add li's to it and they stays when I reload the page. But when trying to do a remove-function I have run into some problem.. **The code below works to delete li's after I reload the page**. But I can't remove li's that have just been added.

when adding an item li I do like this:

```
$(add).click(function(e) {
 if (addtext.value != ""){
  $(listan).append("<li>" + addtext.value + "</li>"); //listan is my <ul>
  localStorage.setItem('todo', listan.innerHTML);
  addtext.value = "";
  color(); //this adds some color to the li and also adds a delete-button
 }
}
```

the color()-function:

```
function color(){
   lin = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

   for (var i = 0; i < lin.length;i++) {
     if (!(lin[i].childNodes.length > 1)){
       $(lin[i]).append("<input type='button' value='ta bort' class='tabort'></intput>"); //adds a deletebutton to all li's that doesnt have one
  
}}}
```

and when removing an item I do like this:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
if (this.id != 'clear'){
  $(this).parent().remove();
  color();
  localStorage.setItem('todo', listan.innerHTML);
  
}
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the new items you've just added don't have the click handler attached for deleting.

You have two options for handling this, one is to use `.live` instead of `.click` (http://api.jquery.com/live/). The other is to wrap the delete code in a function, and call that function after adding a new item.

The first option looks like this (untested):

```
$('input[type="button"]').live('click', function() {
    if (this.id != 'clear'){
      $(this).parent().remove();
      color();
      localStorage.setItem('todo', listan.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

And the second option looks like

```
addDeleteHandler = function($item) {
  $item.click(function() {
    if (this.id != 'clear'){
      $(this).parent().remove();
      color();
      localStorage.setItem('todo', listan.innerHTML);
    }
  });
}

// Modify the add handler
$(add).click(function(e) {
  if (addtext.value != ""){
    $newItem = $("<li>" + addtext.value + "</li>")
    $(listan).append($newItem); //listan is my <ul>
    addDeleteHandler($newItem); // Add delete handler
    localStorage.setItem('todo', listan.innerHTML);
    addtext.value = "";
    color(); //this adds some color to the li and also adds a delete-button
  }
}

// Need this to add delete handlers for items that are already in the list when page loads
addDeleteHandler($('input[type="button"]'))
```

Comment: Live is being deprecated in 1.7, use .on instead

Comment: awesome! thanks! but it should be live(**'click'**, function(){ in the first one right?